# How to send information from MapKit annotation to a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, segue, core-location

Currently I am Pulling JSON from an API and posting it to a MapKit Map. It pulls from the API and parses it into an Array of Class Market, and the size is different for every zip code. Currently I'm trying to get the information for the specific Annotation Callout that I click and send it to a new view controller on the information button click.

Here is my code for the prepare for segue, and when the information button is pressed:

```
    //This method gets ran when the information button is pressed on the Annotation's Callout

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
             calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let market = view.annotation as! Market

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "callout", sender: market)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destination = segue.destination as! CalloutViewController

    destination.market = //Yes this line isn't completed, Not sure how to get the current class from the annotation's callout when it is pressed!

    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Back"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
}
```

Here is the Callout View Controller (The one I'm trying to get the information to segue to.):

```
class CalloutViewController: UIViewController {

let market: Market! = nil

@IBOutlet weak var testView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Comment: why not used Google Map?

Comment: Not familiar with any map frameworks currently. Using MapKit because it was easy for me to implement! I took a look into MapBox as well as Google maps! Maybe next project :D

Comment: Ok Thats good n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just:

```
destination.market = sender as? Market
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes! This worked. I'm still fairly new to swift and everything in general, sorry for this being such a simple task! Did not dawn on me to use the sender, that I am passing into the method from above when I call perform segue!

Thank you,

Comment: @SeanLohman No worries man, glad I could help. Have fun with maps and the rest, these are often the more interesting apps.